# Issue with consuming json from a Xamarin form

Tags: c#, json, xaml, xamarin

So I am trying to consume json in a (C# Xamarin) client app with this code. In the example below I am using a public API with just one result but my code is exactly the same outside of the URL and the number of returned roes..

```
     private static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task FillList()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://ip.jsontest.com");

            List<IpAddress> ipAddress = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<IpAddress>>(json);

            foreach (IpAddress address in ipAddress)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(address.IP.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Walking through he debugger I get to this line

var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://ip.jsontest.com");

But one step further (F11) the debugger jumps to the end of the block and skips over the List fill. Why is it jumping over the List fill and going to the end of the code block? And what do I need to fill the IpAddress list with the result?

Comment: this is probably an artifact of the debugger and async code.  However, you are trying to deserialize a single object into a `List` which will throw an exception.

Comment: The actual API has 30 records and does the exact same thing, I used this as an example because the error behavior is the same and it was public so people could see an example of what i am attempting. Having said that is there an issue with having a list of 1 item?

Comment: `http://ip.jsontest.com` returns a SINGLE object.  It is NOT an array with a single element.  There is a difference.  Put a try/catch around the `DeserializeObject` to see if it is throwing an exception.

Comment: It skips past the try catch. The debugger hits the var await line and then jumps right to the end of the code block.

Comment: as I said before, I suspect this is the debugger being wonky with async code.  Try running without the breakpoint.  Or try hardcoding the response from `GetStringAsync` to see how it behaves.

Comment: Have you tried the link in postman to see if it returns data or not ?